# Why has my zoom feature stopped working in OSX 10.6?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, magic-mouse

For the life of me I can't get the zoom feature to work on OSX 10.6 on my Max Mini. It's a fresh install, I have the wireless mighty mouse with the small grey scroll ball and the small wireless Apple metal keyboard.

I've tried enabling "Zoom using scroll ball whilst holding ^Control" mouse System Preference.

I also tried enabling Zoom in "Universal Access" in the System Preferences.

This did work in OSX 10.5, but seems to have stopped since I installed 10.6.

Comment: I should say I feel a bit thick asking this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but this feature just magically started working again. One day not working, next day working. No reboots or changing configs or swapping batteries on mouse/keyboard.

Comment: The Mighty Mouse has some well known problems with the scroll ball. It becomes dirty quickly and in general may become unresponsive to scrolling. Have you checked if the problem is the scroll ball itself?

Comment: @Paul - the scroll ball worked just fine. I just couldn't use the zoom feature. Has worked ever since it magically started working again.

Comment: Strange. We'll just leave it to computer weirdness then. Sounds like a candidate for [twitter.com/officesunshine](http://twitter.com/officesunshine).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they have some crazy bug. I've been experiencing this too. Just open up the **Accessibility** preference pane, click **Off** and then click **On**, and it will start again. Not sure what is killing it.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Try changing the Zoom while holding to <kbd>option</kbd> in the Mouse panel of System Preferences. Perhaps there's a problem with using control on your system due to a conflict or somesuch.</del>

OK, next thing to check is what screen resolution are you running your monitor at? See if you can zoom at a lower / another resolution. Perhaps the Mac Mini can't handle some resolutions.

Comment: I tried that, no joy.

Comment: It's running at the same resolution as before, 1920 x 1080. No change there.

Comment: This just magically started working again. I have no idea why. but +1 for the time spent, thanks.